# working on array of strings assignment and got stuck on this error "no match for "operator<<"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

   char name[30];
   char answer[10];
   char KeytoCorrection [10][6]={"TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"};
   char remarks [2][7]= {"PASSED", "FAILED"};

int x,y, score=0;

int main()
{

    cout<<"Name: ";
    cin.getline(name,30);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"ANSWERS: "<<endl;

for(x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    cout<<" "<<x+1<<". ";
    cin<<(answer [x] ,6);
}
for(x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    y=strcmpi(answer[x],KeytoCorrection[x]);
    if (y==0)
    {
        score++;
    }

if (score>=6)
{
    strcpy(score,remarks[0]);
}
else
{
    strcpy(score,remarks[1]);
}
cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"SCORE  : ";
cout<<"REMARKS :";
return 0;
}
```

Im new to C++ and this is my assignment in array of strings, I cant really figure out what's wrong with my code. the error "no match for 'operator<<' always appear and I dont know how to solve it.
any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Normally you would use `cin >> answer[x];`, since it is an input stream it doesn't have an output `<<` operator. You could also use `cin.getline` as you did a few lines earlier.

Comment: |error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'char')|     this is the error im getting

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for the help but after I followed ur instruction another sets of error appeared. the Cin.getline resulted to this error |error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::char_type*' {aka 'char*'} [-fpermissive]| in 22,27,35 and 39. its not that im blaming you for it. I just cant really figure out what to do and it's deadline is today's evening. Im sorry for troubling you.

Comment: changing it to cin>>asnwer[x]; also showed the same error. |error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'char')|

Comment: `cin.getline` works with arrays of characters, not a single character which is what `answer[x]` is. If you changed `<<` to `>>` then it is impossible for you to get an error referring to `<<` unless it is on a different line which is possible, I did not exhaustively search your code for errors and to be honest, I wouldn't be surprised if there were more. You might consider learning to use `std::string` which will help you avoid some of these issues.

Comment: okay okay, thank you sir and sorry for troubling you,

Comment: Unless you have a strong reason (learning arrays and char arrays could be one...) I strongly urge you to stick to vectors and strings. Reading and comparing them will be much easier... Come back to those lower level objects later if you want to learn more advanced ways.

Comment: @Hello I posted the full corrected code in answers. You may check.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a couple of things. First of all you need to change how your anwsers variable is declared, so you should change:

```
char answer[10];
```

to

```
char answer[10][6];
```

This is because you have made only one dimensional array of characters meaning you can hold 10 differenct chars. But the inputs are either TRUE or FALSE so you need two dimensions.

Then you just need to change how you read the inputs from

```
cin<<(answer[x] ,6);
```

to

```
cin.getline(answer[x], 6);
```

This should resolve your issues with reading and checking inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete corrected code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

   char name[30];
   char answer[10][6];
   char KeytoCorrection [10][6]={"TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"};
   string remark;//change1
int x,y, score=0;

int main()
{

    cout<<"Name: ";
    cin.getline(name,30);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"ANSWERS: "<<endl;

for(x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    cout<<" "<<x+1<<". ";
    cin.getline(answer [x] ,6);
}
for(x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    y=strcmpi(answer[x],KeytoCorrection[x]);
    if (y==0)
    {
        score++;
    }
}
if (score>=6)
{
    remark="PASSED";//change2
}
else
{
   remark="FAILED";//change2
}
cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"SCORE  : "<<score<<"\n";//change3
cout<<"REMARKS :"<<remark<<"\n";//change3
return 0;
}
```

You may ask if any doubt.